# Analytical query - dense_rank on Spark Streaming

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming, window-functions, dense-rank

I would like to run the below operation on Spark Streaming (structured streaming) Dataframe. But it is giving me error that "Non-time-based windows are not supported on streaming DataFrames/Datasets". Any suggestion on this would be really helpfull.

```
task1_2_1_DF = spark.sql("""select Origin, UniqueCarrier, avg_dep_delay
from(
  select Origin, UniqueCarrier, avg_dep_delay, dense_rank() over (partition by Origin order by avg_dep_delay asc) rnk
  from (
    select Origin, UniqueCarrier, round(avg(DepDelay), 2) avg_dep_delay
    from cc598_task1_src_data
    where Cancelled = 0
    and Origin in ('CMI', 'BWI', 'MIA','LAX', 'IAH', 'SFO')
    group by Origin, UniqueCarrier) tmp
) tmp1
where rnk <=10""")
```

Comment: See this reference from Taghata from Databricks  : http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/Does-partition-by-and-order-by-works-only-in-stateful-case-td31816.html

Comment: The issue could be with windowing specification:

over (partition by deviceId order by timestamp) 
The partition would need to be over a time based column - in your case timestamp . The following should work: